# installing 3rd party dependencies by make

Tags: makefile, dependencies

Installing 3rd party dependencies by make command using makefile is correct way of doing?
Or should we prepare the build environment before of executing make command?

Inside Makefile with a label something's like "prepare". This label will contain `apt-get install <package>` lines to install packages which will be used in LDFlags.

I'm new on C++ development and I don't know if this is good approach or not.

Comment: before of executing make command

Comment: Inside Makefile with a label something's like "prepare". This label will contain apt-get install <package>